# Matching two torn pieces of a paper with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to write a program which would match two torn pieces of paper. For this, I followed along the steps mentioned in this paper [Edge envelope based reconstruction of torn document](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1924611). After implementing the basic pre processing to obtain the contour, corner points and feature extraction, I am finding it difficult to understand the *Matching* section. It says -

> The corners for a  torn piece may be topologically different from
>   those of its  counterparts, depending on the nature of hand movements
>   during  torn process and behavior of the corner detection process.
>   Because of this, total number of points t_p of edge envelope under 
>   consideration and its counterpart will be different. To take care of 
>   this, the edge envelope with the shorter t_p is interpolated to the 
>   length of the longer edge envelope. The outcome of the matching  phase
>   is the matched edges of the torn pieces that are to be joined  to get
>   a single reconstructed document.

Can some one please explain this portion? What does he mean by interpolating the edge envelope and how do we do that? (a code snippet would be valuable addition)

> Due to limitations in the imaging
>   mechanism, the torn piece  having a shear, after being scanned, may
>   contain digital  imperfections and unpredictable rigid
>   transformations. This  creates a lot of ambiguity in matching phase
>   and it can be  overcome by smoothing the edge envelope by filtering.

<strike>What filtering would be suitable in this case?</strike> (according to comment)

Thanks,

Comment: the second question is explained clearly in the paper, please read the paper carefully :)